# Как "перезапустить" owl carousel после ajax запроса?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, owl-carousel

Суть в том, что я динамически подгружаю или убираю элементы из слайдера с помощью ajax. Как после очередного запроса "перезапустить" карусель, что бы она заново подсчитала элементы?

всё, нашла ответ:
у меня была версия jQuery OwlCarousel v1.31
использовала:
$("#owl-demo").data('owlCarousel').destroy();
http://www.jq22.com/demo/jquery-lbt20151019/demos/manipulations.html

Comment: Сделать вызов карусели в функции, и при аяксе вызывать функцию.

Comment: не пересчитывает, пробовала

Comment: Какая версия плагина?

Comment: jQuery OwlCarousel v1.31. я уже нашла ) $("#owl-demo").data('owlCarousel').destroy();